# Send file to linux server

Tags: php

I'm kind of new to php, and I'm trying to send a file through ftp to a computer that's runs 
"Centos 6" (Linux server). 
My code is :

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
$ftp_user = "user";
$ftp_pass = "password";

//set up a connection or die
 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,22) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

 //try to login
 if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
 } else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
 }

  //close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>
```

I'm running the latest versions of Mysql and Apache, and also disable the firewall in the server. I can get to the server with Filezilla but only if I use port 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i did it:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

//Write to a text file
$sftp->put('destinationInServer/filename', file_get_contents('Source/filename'));
echo "Success";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are trying to use FTP protocol to connect to a server that only responds to SFTP (port 22 is SSH and it essentially provides file transfer capabilities), but it is a different protocol altogether.

Try looking at ssh2 functions instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php